# I'm getting an error: "attempt to compare nil with number" in Lua with LOVE2d

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm trying to make my first game with lua & love, it's a simple button clicker game that counts how many times you click a randomly appearing button. I'm trying to add a timer that counts down from 20 on the screen (and eventually make it so that an end screen appears when the timer hits 0).

```
function love.update(dt)
  t = t + 0.01
end

function love.load (timer)
  while t > 0 do
    if t % 1 == 0 then
      timer = 1 + timer
    end
  end
end
```

But I get this error: "attempt to compare nil with number"
I've searched and found `tonumber()` but I don't know how to use it properly.
I'm not even sure that this is the best/a way to make a timer... help?

Comment: Have you initialized variable `t` with `0`?

Comment: And understand: love.load() runs only once at start and love.update is a (infinite) loop (called every frame) as in https://love2d.org/wiki/love.load and https://love2d.org/wiki/love.update described

Answer (score 1):

love will call your `love.load`. When evaluating your while condition `t > 0` it will throw this error because t is not a number but a nil value.
You need to initialize t with a number value befor you can compare it with another number.

I don't mean this offensive but your code does not make too much sense.

First of all you never initialized `t` with a value. So you cannot do any operations on it.

```
function love.update(dt)
  t = t + 0.01
end
```

love.load is executed once at the beginning of your game. `timer` is actually a table value containing the command line arguments to your game. So adding increasing it by 1 does not make any sense.

```
function love.load (timer)
  while t > 0 do
    if t % 1 == 0 then
      timer = 1 + timer
    end
  end
end
```

Even if `t` was a number, `t % 1` is always `0`. So comparing it with `0` doesn't make sense. Plus your code doesn't do anything aside from attempting to increase values by 1 or 0.01 respectively.

Make sure you refer to the love and Lua manuals for everything you use.

https://love2d.org/wiki/love.run  <- this is very important so you understand how those functions are executed.

https://love2d.org/wiki/love

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
function love.load()
    t = 0
end
```

i also noticed the `while t > 0 do` in `love.load()`, this will not work as you expect, instead try putting it in `love.update(dt)`

Answer (score 0):

But if you want the while loop to loop forever, you can just type

```
While true do
   timer = timer + 1
   wait(1)
end
```

If this cannot solve the problem try

```
While true do
   timer = timer + 1
   task.wait(1)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want it to be a countdown, use for loops instead.

```
for i=1,10,-1 do
   timer = i 
   wait(1)
end
```